# Apache Access Control

Tags: svn, apache, mod-dav-svn

I'm trying to configure Apache to allow read only access and ask for user to write to a SVN repository when you are coming from the local network (10.*) but not allow any access unless logged in when coming from external network.

I sort of understand how the Order, Deny, Allow, and Limit directives work but I do not know if it is possible/how to combine them to achieve the desired result.

```
<Location /svn>
  # Set mod_dav_svn settings
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath /mnt/svn
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /mnt/svn/.authz

  # Set Authentication
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Auth Realm"
  AuthUserFile /mnt/svn/.htpasswd

  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.0/8

  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
  Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

I know this will allow all access to any local traffic but ask for login when trying to write from external traffic. This is close to what I want. Any help or suggestions on what to read are greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late reply, but you could add two

The VirtualHost directive requires an ip or * and the port to listen on.  Assuming your hosting on a machine with two network cards, as long as each only listens on the correct card it should do what you wanted....